# In Zero Escape: Virtue's Last Reward (SPOILERS), what is happening when characters show signs of infection with Radical-6?

Tags: zero-escape-virtues-last-reward

There's no way to talk about the plot of *Zero Escape: Virtue's Last Reward* without getting into spoiler territory, but I'll try not to spoil more than necessary to ask my question.  Please let me know if I need to hide any of this inside spoiler tags.

In several of the story paths in ZE:VLR, characters become infected with Radical-6, a virus that slows the processing speed of the brain, which overwhelms the brain with stimuli, making it seem to a person that everything around them is happening at an accelerated speed.  It eventually makes people suicidal if they are not sedated or cured.

But much later in the game, we learn that (almost) all of the characters were infected with Radical-6 at the game's start, so they have all presumably been operating in slow motion without realizing that time was passing faster than it appeared to be.

> "You were infected with Radical-6. Then we gave you the Axelavir, which cured you. The Radical-6 isn't completely gone, though. Some of its symptoms stick around for a while."

This presumably explains why everyone's brain processing speed remained slowed, but they didn't lose their sanity or become suicidal.

Except, there are times during the game where individual characters suddenly seem to come down with a Radical-6 infection.  They comment that everyone suddenly seems to be moving very quickly, like a sped-up video.  Then they become very agitated and, if not restrained, they take their own lives.  There's even one bad ending where this happens to *every* character.

My question is how this can be the case if everyone was already infected with Radical-6 from the start?  How can they get infected "again?"  If their brain processing speed was already slowed, why are they acting as if it is only now being slowed down?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your quoted sentence there is being said to Alice, who was given the Axelavir during the course of the game (in this particular route). Everyone else (apart from Quark) is only given the Axelavir after the end of the game, after Sigma and Phi make their jump back - when "Kyle" is talking with Luna in the "Another Time" segment they discuss this:

> Kyle: How long have I been asleep?
>
> Luna: About five hours in real time.
> For them it would have seemed like a little more than two hours.
>
> Kyle: So they still haven't been treated for their Radical-6?
>
> Luna: No, they've all been given the anti-viral.
> It just takes a while to have an effect...
>
> Kyle: Ah, I see.

That means that during the game, everyone still has untreated Radical-6, so it's not surprising when Alice and Quark (and everyone in the Clover end) progress to full blown Radical-6 and try to commit suicide.

There are still a few inconsistencies - as you say, there are points when Sigma and Quark appear to view time sped up, which knowing what we now know (that they already had Radical-6) means they are seeing things sped up twice as fast as it ought to be. This isn't really explained anywhere from what I can tell. Perhaps Radical-6 has rare instances where it slows the brain function down more than usual for short periods?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more questions arise.  (more huge spoilers!)  Radical-6 is supposed to be the reason why Sigma, Alice, and Clover don't realize they are on the Moon, because their sped-up perception of time makes the 1/6 lunar gravity appear to accelerate objects at 1G.  Phi's apparent superhuman jumping ability is revealed to be just the effect of low gravity.

But then why is Phi the only character we ever see jumping high during the game?  I mean, Quark knew he was on the Moon the whole time-- I'd expect a kid in that situation would be bouncing off the walls half the time.

Comment: @NathanK. Agreed - in the interests of hiding the twist from the player, there are quite a few plot holes.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, Tenmyouji and Quark traveled to the Moon, but then Zero put them to sleep with knockout gas, and the bracelets injected them with the Radical-6 virus while they were sleeping.  When they woke up, their perception of time was distorted, so they probably concluded that they had been taken back to Earth while they were unconscious.  Phi only knew she was on the Moon because she had been hopping between timelines.  The main one that doesn't make sense is Dio, but maybe he just decided to play along with whatever everyone else was saying no matter how odd it seemed.